# Comparing 2 files in linux for different word

Tags: linux, shell

### I have two files like below

file1 has the below words

```
word23.cs
test.cs
only12.cs
```

file 2 has the below words

```
word231.cs
test.cs
only12.cs
```

The above words might change, And now i need to compare the two files using script or linux command to get the different word , i need to compare the file2 with file1 and need to get the output as word23.cs

Thank you

Comment: The above order may change

Comment: `diff =(sort file1) =(sort file2)`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use the "diff" command to compare 2 files:

```
$ diff a.txt b.txt
```

Or, for a unified diff:

```
$ diff -u a.txt b.txt
```

Use `-u0` for a unified diff without context.

Answer (score 2):

You can use `comm`, `diff` or `cmp` command to find different word from files.

Also this trick can work with a `grep` command as follows

```
grep -Fwf file1 file2
```

Comment: consider `-Fw` option. I saw `dot` in both files

Comment: @Kent I updated answer according to your suggestion. Thanks :)

Comment: you forgot the `-f` this time. `grep -Fwf f1 f2`

Comment: Right, yeah I forgot alot he he :D